# How to enable navigation bar on Samsung S8 by programming?

Tags: android

I am building application on Samsung S8.I need enable navigation bar when my application is running.
I figured out a method which hide the Navigation Bar in here `https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation.html`. How to show
the Navigation Bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION

```
void setNavVisibility(boolean visible) {
        int newVis = SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE;
        if (!visible) {
            newVis |= SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE | SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
        }

        // If we are now visible, schedule a timer for us to go invisible.
        if (visible) {
            Handler h = getHandler();
            if (h != null) {
                h.removeCallbacks(mNavHider);
                if (!mMenusOpen && !mPaused) {
                    // If the menus are open or play is paused, we will not auto-hide.
                    h.postDelayed(mNavHider, 3000);
                }
            }
        }

        // Set the new desired visibility.
        setSystemUiVisibility(newVis);
        mTitleView.setVisibility(visible ? VISIBLE : INVISIBLE);
        mPlayButton.setVisibility(visible ? VISIBLE : INVISIBLE);
        mSeekView.setVisibility(visible ? VISIBLE : INVISIBLE);
}
```

This should describe what you are looking for.